# Fully residually free groups and completion

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $G$ be a fully residually free group with a finitely generated profinite completion. Is $G$ necessarily finitely generated?

Comment: I don't think the tag logic is relevant. On the other hand I was wondering if one could replace "f.g. profinite completion" by something even weaker such as "$G/[G,G]G^2$ is finite".